# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in ModbusTCP.OPC.exe

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, exception, syntax-error

All of my Visual Studio Projects are ended up like this. 
The codes below is where VS is pointing me where is wrong in the codes

```
<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
        Me.MainForm = Global.ModbusTCP.OPC.Form1
    End Sub
```

I am Stuck here. Please Help me :(

ERROR MESSAGE:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in ModbusTCP.OPC.exe
>
> Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See
>   Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException' was thrown.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Case Close ! I found out that it throws an exception because I am trying to access an activeX component without initializing (createcontrol)  it first.